# How can I calculate the following limit? $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln n}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Can you give me just a hint to calculate the following limit? $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(\ln n)^{\ln n}}$$ I am trying using the squeeze rule without success. I tried also l'Hopital but the limit become tougher.

Thank you.

Comment: Take the logarithm.

Comment: @Charlie Please, instead of writing $->$ by typing `->`, write $\to$ by typing `\to` or `\rightarrow`.

Comment: @Aðøbe Ok, I'm sorry. I'll do it from now on.

Comment: @Charlie No problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\ln(n) \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. So, $\ln(n)^{\ln(n)} \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Hence the limit is $0$.

Comment: Please, write $\ln$ by typing `\ln` instead of $ln$ made by typing `ln`.

Comment: ok- will do. Thanks @Aðøbe

Comment: You're welcome! ;-)

Comment: So $\infty^\infty$ is not an indeterminate form right?

Comment: @Charlie: No- it is infinite.

Comment: @Charlie $\infty^\infty$ is not an [indeterminate form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#List_of_indeterminate_forms).